# PHP/MySQL Array to table with Aggregate calculations

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I have the need to generate a PHP page that displays all details stored in an array (from a MySQL request) in a way that shows a count/summary of each similar line item.

Here is an example dataset collected from an SQL query (it has been structure to ORDER BY Workgroup, ProductCode):

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | ProductCode | Description | Workgroup |   Status  |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|  2 |     A123    |    Coke     |  Finance  |  Ordered  |
|  4 |     A123    |    Coke     |  Finance  |  Rejected |
|  1 |     A123    |    Coke     |  Finance  |  Rejected |
|  6 |     B111    |    Pepsi    |  Finance  |  Ordered  |
|  5 |     B111    |    Pepsi    |  Finance  |  Rejected |
|  8 |     B111    |    Pepsi    |  Finance  |  Rejected |
| 10 |     B112    |    Fanta    |  Finance  |  Ordered  |
| 42 |     A123    |    Coke     | Management|  Ordered  |
| 16 |     A123    |    Coke     | Management|  Ordered  |
| 11 |     B112    |    Fanta    | Management|  Rejected |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

These details have been stored in a PHP array as follows:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 2
                [ProductCode] => A123
                [Description] => Coke
                [Workgroup] => Finance
                [Status] => Ordered
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 4
                [ProductCode] => A123
                [Description] => Coke
                [Workgroup] => Finance
                [Status] => Rejected
            )
             ...etc
)
```

What I require is to spit the data out in multiple tables separated by WorkGroup, with a single summary line per Product with each individual line item listed beneath (it doesn't strictly need to be a html table, just some HTML construct that is able to represent the line-items)

From the 10 example entries I've shown, it would need to output the following:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| FINANCE TEAM                                           |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| Coke      Total: 3     Ordered: 1     Rejected: 2      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|  2 |     A123    |    Coke     |  Finance  |  Ordered  |
|  4 |     A123    |    Coke     |  Finance  |  Rejected |
|  1 |     A123    |    Coke     |  Finance  |  Rejected |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| Pepsi    Total: 3     Ordered: 1      Rejected: 2      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|  6 |     B111    |    Pepsi    |  Finance  |  Ordered  |
|  5 |     B111    |    Pepsi    |  Finance  |  Rejected |
|  8 |     B111    |    Pepsi    |  Finance  |  Rejected |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| Fanta    Total: 1     Ordered: 1      Rejected: 0      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 10 |     B112    |    Fanta    |  Finance  |  Ordered  |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+

+--------------------------------------------------------+
| MANAGEMENT TEAM                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| Coke      Total: 2     Ordered: 2     Rejected: 0      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 42 |     A123    |    Coke     | Management|  Ordered  |
| 16 |     A123    |    Coke     | Management|  Ordered  |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| Fanta      Total: 1    Ordered: 0     Rejected: 1      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 11 |     B112    |    Fanta    | Management|  Rejected |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I can elaborate further if what I require isn't clear enough.

ANY help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you start a post with "I have ... and I need ..." you should probably evaluate if you've written any code to try to solve your problem.

Comment: Apologies if you think I was being too forward. I've attempted to solve my problem, none of which was worth posting because it was complete and utter garbage. As I said: "ANY help would be GREATLY appreciated."

Comment: Complete and utter garbage is more to work with than nothing. If you have something, we can point out where you went wrong or where you can do better.

Answer (score 0):

php arrays are really easily converted into tree like structures. You sound like you know how to program, so I wont sendtehfullcodez because I think you can handle some nested loops to generate the final html yourself after its put into a more convenient format.

```
$tree = array();
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    extract($row);
    $tree[$Workgroup][$Description][] = $row;
}
print_r($tree);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can see the usefulness of converting it into an "organised" tree like structure. I'm still having a bit of difficulty conceptualising how I can look through the array, recording a count of each specific item per workgroup, then spit it out with the summary followed by detailed line-item breakdown.

Any further nudges in the right direction?